# Is Red John's motive ever revealed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mentalist

I have been rewatching *[The Mentalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mentalist)* on TV lately, and it seems to me that Red John's motive is never revealed. I could find nothing on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_John) and various fan-made wikias, so I wonder:

**Is Red John's motive ever revealed**?

Or do I miss somethig (or some episode)?

I am not referring to Patrick Jane's family, I know what happened in that case, I mean in general: **why did Red John kill all those people.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Red John was a psychopathic serial killer...and so needed no "motive" as such.

From a [**wikia**](http://thementalist.wikia.com/wiki/Red_John)

> Red John's personality can be described as the classic example of a psychopath: narcissistic, with zero empathy towards others and a tendency to manipulate those around him. He has constructed a god-like or messiah figure of himself - something that he values and furiously retaliates against people who belittle this.

However, when Patrick Jane *profiles* Red John on TV (in his old psychic role) Red John is offended and takes revenge by killing Patricks wife and child.

Thereafter, Patrick devotes his life to tracking down Red John and killing him.